# Java and Javascript methods of controlling display, pixel per pixel

Tags: java, javascript

I'm working on a new project that will require some 3d rendering. I am planning on writing all of the calculations for each individual pixel (bypassing a graphics engine), and I'd like to do it with Javascript, but I don't know if there's a way. Posting HTML to display thousands of pixels is way too slow. I need something quick and responsive, so I'm considering using JAVA.

My question is, do either of these have the ability to perform calculations on individual pixels, quickly? And how would I access the display in such a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time to get familiar with OpenGL, you could use OpenGL in java:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL

This would allow you to directly manipulate a specified OpenGL-frame. Kindof like what runescape does.

Comment: Don't forget WebGL (OpenGL for Javascript), if you prefer Javascript to java, both have compatibility for shaders..